# .ppt , .doc or .ppt file display in ios app

Tags: ios, powerpoint

I need to download a file from api like

http://52.76.226.179/aapc-social-web/sites/default/files/media_docs/2009/content-601938936.ppt

and display a preview of that in my ios app.

Please help.

[I have used the quick look framework and UIDocumentInteractionController show me something like this. please see the image and suggest something.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxQe3.jpg)

Comment: This may help you : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/QLPreviewController

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content-601938936" ofType:@"ppt"];
        UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
        
        // Configure Document Interaction Controller
        [documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
        
        [documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UIDocumentInteractionController][1]` Is what you are looking for.
The main difference respect `QLPreviewController`, is that it can display a preview and also it can display a `UiActionSheet` or popover showing the applications compatible with that format and delegate the display of the document to them.
It's super easy to use it. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html)

.

Comment: I have used it.
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content-601938936" ofType:@"ppt"];
        UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
        
        // Configure Document Interaction Controller
        [documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
        
        [documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

but show me file like http://i.stack.imgur.com/fxQe3.jpg 
please suggest.

Comment: I think that this happens when the file is not compatible for preview , are you sure that the path is correct?

Comment: I think you are right there is problem with file. I try with another file worked like charm. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

import this pkg

```
  #import <QuickLook/QuickLook.h>
```

Use this code in View controller.

```
QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
previewController.delegate=self;
previewController.dataSource=self;

previewController.view.frame = self.conditionsofUseView.bounds;
[self.conditionsofUseView addSubview:previewController.view];
[self addChildViewController:previewController];
[previewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[previewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
```

Add These Delegate methodes

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller
 {
    return 1;
 }

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
 {


NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"docFileName" ofType:@"file type"];  //doc,ppt,pdf etc 

return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view the Office files, have a look at:

- [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS: Quick Look Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html).
- [Quick Look Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html)

**Quick Look Framework** supports a lot of file formats as you can see in the links above. It is available in iOS 4.0 and later.

You can also use **UIWebView** to display them. See [Using UIWebView to display select document types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html).